# Kibana discover tab doesn't reflect the real-time logs.

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have a ELK setup with Elastic Search, LogStash and Kibana running on one VM. The logs are shipped from another service using filebeat from another VM.

The version of the Elastic Search is: 0:6.2.4-1

I enabled Auto refresh in Kibana with refresh at every 5 seconds and also selected Last 15 minutes window to display the logs.

Issues:

1. When file beat is started, it starts shipping logs right away. I can see this from the file beat logs. However, new logs will get reflected in Kibana only after some time with delay. Behavior is not consistent and I can see the delay up to 30 minutes in some cases. Is this expected ?
2. If, when refresh on Kibana screen is disabled, (i.e change from 5 seconds to "off"), wait for 15 minutes and then enable the refresh back (from "off" to 5 seconds). What should be the behavior ? All these 15 minutes, log stash and ES are actually receiving the logs, just that Kibana refresh is disabled. 
   a) will it quickly show the logs from previous 15 minutes and start showing the new logs in real-time ?
   b) or this 15 minutes delay continue to be there ? I mean, from now on do we always see the logs on Kibana with 15 minutes delay ?
3. When File beat process is stopped, Kibana still shows some logs and keeps refreshing. My expectation is that, once the File beat is stopped, the log refresh on kibana should also be stopped with a small delay (in the order of seconds). But I see the logs refresh continues to happen for next 1 hour or so. Why is Kibana having this behavior ? Am I missing some thing ? I also observed that when Kibana doesn't have any new logs to show, I think it is showing the older logs. Not 100% sure, but can this happen ?

I searched over google and stack over flow, but couldnt actually get any useful information. Either a quick explanation and solution or any pointers/links to help on this will be useful for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- logstash receive logs (in your case, from filebeats) and send them to elasticsearch, perhaps doing some filtering or parsing of the logs. By default, the log will be saved in elasticsearch with the date at which the log was received by logstash; this default date can be replaced by a date parsed from the log (in the field `timestamp`).
- elasticsearch save the logs and can returns them on demand
- kibana retrieve in elasticsearch the logs according to its parameters, in your case, logs with a `timestamp` from the last 15 min

To answer your questions:

1. I don't know why exactly, I would need more information. You should ask a question with more details (configurations, sample logs, data shown in Kibana)
2. The `Last 15 min` of kibana ask to elasticsearch for the logs with `timestamp` between now and now-15 min. So it's going to be c) kibana shows the logs in real-time, ignoring those received before now-15 min.
3. The log refresh in Kibana will continues until you ask it to stop, that logstash stop receiving new log won't stop the kibana auto-refresh. Kibana will continue to ask elasticsearch for logs with `timestamp` between now and now-15 min. So if kibana continues to show logs after 15 min has elapsed since filebeat has been stopped, it means there are logs which were timestamped in the future.

---

For your information, you're not supposed to ask multiple questions in one StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. #2 and #3 above are useful and helpful. Btw, which part of my question makes you feel that I don't know that ELK stack has different piece of software in it ?

Comment: @user2896235 I misunderstood a part of your question when I first read it. I'll edit this part out.